# How can I get the index of the ordered data for a matrix?

Tags: r

The requirement is simple. For example, we can get a matrix like this:

```
n "matix"
> d
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

I want to get the index of the ordered data for the d, such as:

```
(2,2)
(1,2)
(2,1)
(1,1)
```

I think R must have a function to do this work. Any one knows that? Thank you.

Comment: see `row(d)`, `col(d)`, `order(d)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `order()` to order the cells, then use `arrayInd` to get the indices

```
d<-matrix(1:4, nrow=2)
arrayInd(order(d, decreasing=T), .dim=dim(d))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    2
# [2,]    1    2
# [3,]    2    1
# [4,]    1    1
```